# Bootstrap: Can't get grunt to run the server

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs

I downloaded the source code from getbootstrap.com and ran npm install, then `grunt connect` without any luck.

I see this in my terminal:

```
Running "connect:server" (connect) task
Started connect web server on 0.0.0.0:3000
```

But when I navigate over, all I see is this:

[image]

What have I missed? I feel I've missed something basic here but unsure why I'm not seeing anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

In the Internet Protocol version 4 the address `0.0.0.0` is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non applicable target.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,bootstrap doc is not build in grunt, you need to install Jekyll to run the web local.so you need install ruby first,and install gem second,then install jekyll,finally,use

```
jekyll serve
```

to run the local server.
watch the [guide](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/)

Comment: grunt can use to build a new bootstrap.css,like grunt dist-css